# Magento 2 frontend ui components grid for company users page not working.it's always spinning

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Magento 2 company users page in frontend not loading.it's always spinning with loader.if we checked in console i am getting the following error.

[image]

The Company Users page is rendering by using ui_components.can any one please me help on that to resolve the issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it your custom grid? if it's your custom grid, please post your code.

Comment: No it's not custom grid it's default magento only.In magento2(cloud) there is one module module-company from that module it's rendering.file path is frontend/ui_component/company_users_listing.xml